# XEN CPUID Exit handler

Tags: virtual-machine, citrix, xen, hypervisor, cpuid

What happens when cpuid instruction is executed in domU kernel? I was checking xc_cpuid_x86.c file in /tools/libxc but looks like XEN is not trapping cpuid instruction at all. I was not able to find out where the exit handler is written in XEN for cpuid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.